# How to fix? error: The named parameter 'child' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter at [application_1]

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Excuse me, before I want to explain that this is the result of converting from figma using [this](https://www.dhiwise.com/)
So after I downloaded, I got an error in one of the codes

Before that, I used

> Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.22572.201], locale en-US)
> Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
> 32.1.0-rc1)

```
import 'controller/splashscreen_controller.dart';
import 'package:application_1/core/app_export.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class SplashscreenScreen extends GetWidget<SplashscreenController> {
  @override
  Widget builder(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
        body: Container(
          width: size.width,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              width: size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: getHorizontalSize(
                    11.56,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "lbl_skylink".tr,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: AppStyle.textStylePoppinsmedium34.copyWith(
                    fontSize: getFontSize(
                      34,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: getVerticalSize(
                        7.22,
                      ),
                      bottom: getVerticalSize(
                        5.78,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      height: getVerticalSize(
                        39.00,
                      ),
                      width: getHorizontalSize(
                        43.33,
                      ),
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        ImageConstant.imgVector5,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: getVerticalSize(
                              187.00,
                            ),
                            bottom: getVerticalSize(
                              0.01,
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            height: getVerticalSize(
                              192.99,
                            ),
                            width: getHorizontalSize(
                              375.00,
                            ),
                            child: SvgPicture.asset(
                              ImageConstant.imgBackgroundillu,
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For the build version I use on build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The Error message is shown when you try to define child parameter to widgets that does not have "child" paramete, in this case `SvgPicture.asset`

But the main problem in your case is
that it seems that **the code you have downloaded is corrupted**. It seems to have several fallacies.

Mainly widgets are wrongly nested and also are defining child parameters to widgets which does not have "child" parameters.

below is a code which I assumed your code was meant to be. Try it and see if it works.

```dart
import 'controller/splashscreen_controller.dart';
import 'package:application_1/core/app_export.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class SplashscreenScreen extends GetWidget<SplashscreenController> {
  @override
  Widget builder(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
        body: Container(
          width: size.width,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              width: size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: getHorizontalSize(
                        11.56,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "lbl_skylink".tr,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: AppStyle.textStylePoppinsmedium34.copyWith(
                        fontSize: getFontSize(
                          34,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: getVerticalSize(
                        7.22,
                      ),
                      bottom: getVerticalSize(
                        5.78,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      height: getVerticalSize(
                        39.00,
                      ),
                      width: getHorizontalSize(
                        43.33,
                      ),
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        ImageConstant.imgVector5,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: getVerticalSize(
                        187.00,
                      ),
                      bottom: getVerticalSize(
                        0.01,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      height: getVerticalSize(
                        192.99,
                      ),
                      width: getHorizontalSize(
                        375.00,
                      ),
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        ImageConstant.imgBackgroundillu,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```